# Migration from TDM to All IP: any security issues?

Tags: network, ip, phone

My phone operator is slowly abandoning TDM (Time Division Multiplexing) to replace it with IP connections. What are the security risked related to this change? will all the phone line be like in a big LAN? will it be easier to do packet injections, DDoS, or hacking?

I don't really understand what is the technology behind this and what are the new risk we will see?